# Draw NE555 timer as a rectangle (4 pins-4pins)

Tags: circuitikz

Hello I need to draw a NE555 timer in `circuitikz`.

I want to draw it like it is represented on the following figure (next part on pin 3) :

[image]

How can I do it ? Add pin number from 1 to 8 and add legend inside could be great !

Thanks

Comment: Hi!  Welcome! What have you tried? Look at the `circuitikz` manual, in the section dedicated to chips; there are several examples... Look also at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596320/circuitikz-drawing-an-ic-with-pin-on-the-top-and-bottom

Answer (score 1):

This can get you started (although it's way better, in my opinion, to use a more logical structure for the chip [as in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596320/circuitikz-drawing-an-ic-with-pin-on-the-top-and-bottom), because drawing the chip upside-down is, well, a bit tasteless...):

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.72mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \node [dipchip, rotate=180](NE) at(0,0) {\ctikzflipxy{NE555}};
    \draw (NE.pin 3) node[above, font=\tiny\ttfamily]{OUT} -- ++(1,0)
        node[npn, anchor=B](Q){};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]